# Is there something like Siri Shortcuts for Google Assistant?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

As I previously did with my iPhone I'd like to tell my Android phone: "Ok Google, open my main door"

that called a webhook url that then opened my front door.

How can I accomplish that with Google Assistant? Is there something like Shortcuts so I can set a phrase that then just calls an url?

btw: I tried it with google assistant action - hwr, there you can only publish your actions publicly.
I also tried "Routines" but as the action it does not open websites with the "open website" command that have a subdomain or a port set, which my url does.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) to create an "Applet" that accepts commands that you've defined from your Google Assistant and sends an HTTP command that you choose.